# Audio file not playing inside a firefox addon, audio element disappears with no error

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, html5-audio

Any ideas why the `audio` tag is disappearing below when I try `play` the file?

The file exists and firefox (im running FF46) should support it.

Console output:

```
bob@work:~/git/addon $ jpm run -b ~/apps/firefox/firefox
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on addon
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
console.log: addon: file:///home/bob/Downloads/5secs.ogg
bob@work:~/git/addon $ ls /home/bob/Downloads/5secs.ogg 
/home/bob/Downloads/5secs.ogg
```

Javascript:

```
console.log('file://' + dir + '/' + filename);
document.getElementById('player').src = 'file://' + dir + '/' + filename;
document.getElementById('player').play();
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="player" preload="auto" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Is that audio element attached in a page-worker?

Comment: No, the `<audio>` tag is on a `Panel`, the `Panel` has a `contentScriptFile` which contains the `js` in the question to load a file and play it.

Comment: There is a security error when you open the main browser console (ctrl+shift+j). `Security Error: Content at resource://test/data/audio.html may not load or link to file:///` This means you can't play audio using a panel. I think you could just put the file inside the data directory. If that's not possible, there is one more solution, let me know and I'll explain it.